# want to replace $ with HTML ul tag while using .replace() function in python

Tags: python, html

```
contents = open('filename.txt.',"r")
with open("filename.html", "w") as e:
    for lines in contents.readlines():
        e.write("$" + lines + "<br>\n")
```

want to replace $ with UL tag of HTML while using .replace() method of python so it looks like :

- Coffee

instead of:

$ Coffee

Comment: Something like `lines.replace('$', '<ul>')`?

Comment: **1.** Do not use `readlines()` iterate over file line by line instead: `for lines in contents`; **2.** Remove trailing `\n` using `rstrip()`: `lines.rstrip()`; **3.** To replace substring you can use `replace()`: `lines.rstrip().replace("$", "<ul>")`.

Comment: like this;??
contents = open('filename.txt.',"r")
with open("filename.html", "w") as e:
    e.write("<ul>")
    for lines in contents:
        lines.rstrip().replace("$", "<ul>")